# SQL Trigger: Inserting a row in a table after an insert on another table, if a given value doesn't already exist in the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, sql-insert

As the title says, I'm trying to insert a row in one table, triggered after an insertion on another table, but only if a given value doesn't already exist in the first table.

Example:

I have one table, **countries**, which stores countries and their id's:

**Countries**

```
id   country 
1    England 
2    France  
...  ...
```

I have another table, **events**, which stores information about events as follows:

**Events**

```
id  timestamp   city    country
1   13435636    London  England
2   45635742    Paris   France
... ... ... ...
```

What I want to do: create a trigger so that after an insertion on the **events** table, insert a new row in the **countries** table with the country that the event occurred in, but only if that country doesn't already exist in the **countries** table.

What I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update
AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (New.country)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country = New.country)

CREATE TRIGGER Update
AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country = New.country)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (New.country)
    END

CREATE TRIGGER Update
AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country = New.country)
        INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (New.country)
```

Along with some other variations, and all I get are syntax errors (error #1064).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Update
    AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (New.country)
        WHERE New.country NOT IN (SELECT country FROM countries)
   END
```